# Class Page Not Found in PHP Application

Tags: php

PHP Application running as docker container throws below error under increased load. Unable to figure out the root cause. Any advice would help?

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Page' not found in /var/www/html/vendor/silverstripe/errorpage/src/ErrorPage.php`

This is the code of ErrorPage.php:

```php
<?php  
namespace SilverStripe\ErrorPage;

use Page;
use SilverStripe\Assets\File;
use SilverStripe\Assets\Storage\GeneratedAssetHandler;
use SilverStripe\CMS\Controllers\ModelAsController;
use SilverStripe\CMS\Model\SiteTree;
use SilverStripe\Control\Controller;
use SilverStripe\Control\Director;
use SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest;
use SilverStripe\Control\HTTPResponse;
use SilverStripe\Control\HTTPResponse_Exception;
use SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector;
use SilverStripe\Dev\Debug;

class ErrorPage extends Page
{
.....
}
```

Comment: it says what it is, class Page is used in ErrorPage.php but is not found. Maybe you forgot to import it?

Comment: Can you share the code of ErrorPage.php?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

The Page class is imported with `use Page;`.

Is there a file named Page.php in the same folder as SilverStripe/ErrorPage.php?

If not then that's the problem and `use Page;` is not correct and should be changed to the correct path or the file should be created with correct code.

Comment: `<?php

namespace SilverStripe\ErrorPage;

use Page;
use SilverStripe\Assets\File;
use SilverStripe\Assets\Storage\GeneratedAssetHandler;
use SilverStripe\CMS\Controllers\ModelAsController;
use SilverStripe\CMS\Model\SiteTree;
use SilverStripe\Control\Controller;
use SilverStripe\Control\Director;
use SilverStripe\Control\HTTPRequest;
use SilverStripe\Control\HTTPResponse;
use SilverStripe\Control\HTTPResponse_Exception;
use SilverStripe\Core\Injector\Injector;
use SilverStripe\Dev\Debug;
class ErrorPage extends Page
{
.....
}
`

Comment: this is how the developer has written it. It only happens when there is an increase in load.. assuming it hits the error page and throws a class not found error

Comment: Is there a file named Page.php in the same folder as SilverStripe/ErrorPage.php? If not then that's the problem and `use Page;` is not correct and should be changed to the correct path.

Comment: you are correct.. there is no page.php in the same folder as ErrorPage.php . Many thanks, I will sort it out from here

Comment: @apark: Great you can fix it now. I've added your code to the question and updated my answer. Could you please accept the answer for future visitors?

Comment: We had a look at it and this errorpage module gets installed via "composer.phar install". We cant manually change it.. Do you know if we can alter the location of this install (errorpage especially) or should we manually copy the 'page' class into this directory?
https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-errorpage